# Mostrar paginas segun tipo de usuario

Tags: javascript, login

Tengo 3 paginas: `article.html, receipt.html y output.html`

y tengo 3 perfiles: `admin` este tiene acceso a las `3` paginas, usuario `output` que solamente podrá ver la pagina `output.html` y `receipt`, a `receipt.html`

Lo que yo hice fue que de la pagina `receipt` elimine los enlaces a `article.html` y `output`, así como de `output` `article y receipt`.

Pero me acabo de dar cuenta, que no resulto como esperaba, ya que al ser admin y tener acceso a las 3 paginas, por ejemplo si voy a la pagina output, obviamente las otras 2 paginas ya no me aparecen y no puedo regresar.

Por lo que necesito saber como ocultar de alguna manera ocultar las paginas cuando este en receipt y output, así como ver las 3 paginas al ser admin sin necesidad de eliminar los enlaces.

Este es mi `JS` donde valido el tipo de usuario y lo mando a la pagina que le corresponde:

```
function login(id_user,password_user)
{
    //debugger
    console.log('ENTRE A LOGIN');
    var id_user =document.getElementById("user").value;
    var password_user =document.getElementById("pass").value;
    console.log(id_user);
    console.log(password_user);

//validar que no esten en blanco
    if (id_user  === '' || password_user == '') {
        $("#id_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
        $("#password_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
        document.getElementById("errorLogin").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("errorLogin").innerHTML = "No puedes dejar campos en blanco, completa la informacion.";
        document.location.href="#errorLogin";
    }
    //si no estan en blanco avanza al ajax.
    else{
    var fd = new FormData();
                var data =  $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "apis/user.php?id_user="+id_user+"&password_user="+password_user,//A que archivo enviara los parametros
                 data: fd,//Parametros que se enviaran
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data){
                 var jsonParse = JSON.parse(data);
                 var tipo_usuario = jsonParse.user.type_user;
                  console.log(tipo_usuario);
                 console.log('ENTRE AJAX');
                 if(tipo_usuario == "admin")
                 {
                     console.log('article');
                        window.location.href='./article.html';
                 }
                 else if(tipo_usuario == "receipt")
                 {
                      console.log('receipt');
                     window.location.href='./receipt.html';
                 }
                 else if(tipo_usuario == "output")
                 {
                      console.log('output');
                     window.location.href='./output.html';
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     alert('usuario no existe');
                     return false;
                 }
                },
                }); //fin ajax
            }
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta en sí, pero hay dos cosas que llaman la atención: 1) estás pasando la contraseña en la dirección de la página (con un `get`), eso es inseguro y una mala práctica, deberías usar `post` en su lugar; 2) lo que ve un usuario no debería controlarse con JS, debería ser del lado del servidor: los usuarios pueden cambiar el JS y toda la lógica de programa que tienes dejaría de funcionar (puedes ocultar los enlaces con CSS/JS, pero deberías verificar en el servidor que el usuario tiene acceso (algo que puedes estar haciendo pero que no se ve en el código compartido).

Comment: En tu `if` mandas al **admin** a tu pagina `article.html`, dentro de esa página quiero suponer que hay etiquetas `<a href=""></a>` que te mandan a `output.html` y `receipt.html`, si así fuera por qué no envías por GET la misma variable **tipo_usuario** y así puedes validar quién está intentando ingresar, espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Si te entendi, vere que puedo hacer..

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar esto. Primero seteas el tipo de usuario cuando se loguea . EJ

```
$client = "premium";

if($client=='premium'){
   include 'pag.php';
} else if($client=='usuario') {
       include 'pag2.php';
} else {
   echo "<html><center><h2>No estás logueado</h2>";
}
```

También podrias hacer que cuando valide que no este en blanco setee que es un no-logueado

```
if (id_user  === '' || password_user == '') {
    $client = "no-logueado";
    $("#id_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
    $("#password_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
    document.getElementById("errorLogin").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("errorLogin").innerHTML = "No puedes dejar campos en blanco, completa la informacion.";
    document.location.href="#errorLogin";
}
```

y ahora quedaria asi el otro código.

```
if($client=='no-logueado'){
   echo "<html><center><h2>No estás logueado</h2>";
} else {
    include 'pag.php';
}
```

Espero que te sirva :).